# Implementing Autocomplete on a Wordpress site

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, autocomplete

So I'm working on a Wordpress site which is a directory for a variety of business types (doctors, lawyers, realtors, etc). I'd like to implement a live autosuggestion feature on one of my theme's existing searchbars. I managed to follow this tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) and successfully implemented it.

However, this implementation of the autosuggestion immediately takes you to a dedicated link specified in an XML file. That is, when you click on the suggestion you'd like to select (ie. Dentist) it automatically takes you to that page. All I'd like the autosuggestion to do is fill the relevant text box with the selected text.

I realize that this change would probably be done through PHP, which is why I'm having trouble. I'm comfortable with HTML, CSS, and Javascript, but have little experience with PHP and would appreciate andy guidance or resources anyone could help me with.

I would also be open to any solutions to my problem that have nothing to do with the way I approached the problem.

A link to the site in question (hosted on a development domain): http://temp4.dotdevelopment.net/

The relevant search box is the box with the default text "What are you looking for?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-created the scripts for you. Feel free to use and modify the code.

**THE SCRIPTS**

Step #1: See [*SCRIPT #1* and *SCRIPT #2*](https://pastebin.com/kYTtmd5h) and remove both scripts from the page.

Step #2: Download [this JS file](https://pastebin.com/NUFAqtFy) and upload it to your site (e.g. to *wp-content/themes/listify-child/js/*).

Step #3: Load the JS file from the page (e.g. add the following before `</body>`):

```
<script src="wp-content/themes/listify-child/js/custom-auto-suggest.js"></script>
```

Or you can use the following PHP snippet to *properly* load the JS file on the page:

```
// Add this code snippet to functions.php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    // Load the JS file only on the home page.
    if ( is_home() ) {
        // Here, I assumed the JS file is at wp-content/themes/listify-child/js/custom-auto-suggest.js
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-auto-suggest', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/custom-auto-suggest.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), '20180302' );
    }
} );
```

**CUSTOM CSS**

Add these to the theme's stylesheet/CSS file:

```
/* Styles for the AJAX auto-suggest results. */

#livesearch .ac-item {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#livesearch .ac-item.active,
#livesearch .ac-item:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hey Sally, had a quick follow up question, I implemented your solution and it works great, but the autosearch isn't changing which XML file it is accessing. Essentially it behaves as if the category selected is always "All categories" rather than changing based on which option is selected in the first dropdown. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Also thanks so much for helping me out, the code is very well documented and works great I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @Bazoqa. I could see that you've already implemented the script on the page, and I've tested the auto-suggest feature, and it works well on my end? When I change the category and type a keyword, the results are taken from the selected category only. So, can you explain the "the autosearch isn't changing which XML file it is accessing"? Using a screencast, if necessary, so that I can see what needs to be changed/adjusted or even fixed.

Comment: For example, when the "Lawyer" category is selected (first selection box), I can type "Chiro" in the third box, and "Chiropractic Physical Therapy" appears as a suggestion, which should only happen if "Doctor" is selected rather than "Lawyer" in the first box. In your javascript file I believe the "// Define the different search URLs" portion of code is not selecting the appropriate php file.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't happen on my end. I'll post a screencast for you. (But it will take time, esp. to upload it.)

Comment: Nevermind it was an internal issue, I took care of it. Thanks again for all the help Sally!